# How to make unequal length strings equal to one another?

Tags: r, string, split, substring

Is there a way to make one string match the length of another string? Basically what needs to happen is the string in value2 should be made to the size of value3's string.

The original data frame is as follows

| type | value1 | value2 | value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Inner | 0.52,0.11,0.08 | 1.3,1.9,2.8,1.08 | 56.9,60.1,1.0 |
| Outer | 0.12,3.09,5.91,0.01 | 0.1,0.35,1.93,9.31,7.19,3.29 | 93.53,0.87,0.65,0.98 |
| Median | 0.10 | 8.10,9.56 | 3.10 |

The desired output is

| type | value1 | value2 | value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Inner | 0.52,0.11,0.08 | 1.3,1.9,2.8 | 56.9,60.1,1.0 |
| Outer | 0.12,3.09,5.91,0.01 | 0.1,0.35,1.93,9.31 | 93.53,0.87,0.65,0.98 |
| Median | 0.10 | 8.10 | 3.10 |

As you can see the original value2 Inner had 4 numbers separated by commas and value3 had 3, etc. The desired output removes
the extra value from the string in value2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`Base R` - split the 'value2', 'value1' columns by `,`, get the `lengths` of the `list` output from `value1` and use that to subset the list elements of `value2` and `paste` those to create a single string

```
df1$value2 <- unlist(Map(function(x,y) paste(x[seq_len(y)], collapse=","),
     strsplit(df1$value2, ","), lengths(strsplit(df1$value1, ","))))
```

-output

```
> df1
    type              value1             value2               value3
1  Inner      0.52,0.11,0.08        1.3,1.9,2.8        56.9,60.1,1.0
2  Outer 0.12,3.09,5.91,0.01 0.1,0.35,1.93,9.31 93.53,0.87,0.65,0.98
3 Median                0.10               8.10                 3.10
```

---

Another option is to split with `cSplit` for columns 'value1', 'value2', `filter` to keep only rows having non-NA elements, grouped by 'type', 'value3' `paste` (`str_c`) the columns 'value1', 'value2'

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
cSplit(df1, c("value1", "value2"), sep = ",", "long") %>% 
   filter(if_all(c(value1,value2), complete.cases)) %>% 
   group_by(type, value3) %>%
   summarise(across(value1:value2, ~ str_c(.x, collapse=",")), 
         .groups = 'drop') %>% 
   select(names(df1))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  type   value1              value2             value3              
  <chr>  <chr>               <chr>              <chr>               
1 Inner  0.52,0.11,0.08      1.3,1.9,2.8        56.9,60.1,1.0       
2 Median 0.1                 8.1                3.10                
3 Outer  0.12,3.09,5.91,0.01 0.1,0.35,1.93,9.31 93.53,0.87,0.65,0.98
```

---

Or an easier option will be to remove the substring from the value2 by capturing the digits, dot (`[0-9]+`) as a group based on the 'value1' values

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(value2 = str_replace(value2, sprintf("(%s).*", 
       str_replace_all(value1, "[0-9.]+", "[0-9.]+")), "\\1"))
```

-output

```
   type              value1             value2               value3
1  Inner      0.52,0.11,0.08        1.3,1.9,2.8        56.9,60.1,1.0
2  Outer 0.12,3.09,5.91,0.01 0.1,0.35,1.93,9.31 93.53,0.87,0.65,0.98
3 Median                0.10               8.10                 3.10
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(type = c("Inner", "Outer", "Median"), value1 = c("0.52,0.11,0.08", 
"0.12,3.09,5.91,0.01", "0.10"), value2 = c("1.3,1.9,2.8,1.08", 
"0.1,0.35,1.93,9.31,7.19,3.29", "8.10,9.56"), value3 = c("56.9,60.1,1.0", 
"93.53,0.87,0.65,0.98", "3.10")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```